# Is it okay to self-answer a broad question?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

I'd like to write up some self-answered questions: is it okay if these are broader in scope than what we'd usually allow? Is it okay if they are basically (short) tutorials?

As an example: for a gift I want to make a hollow book. As I'm working on it, I'd like to take pictures, so I can upload them and shortly describe the different steps.

Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the purpose is to create site FAQ or canonical QA, that often relies on the question being intentionally broad by design.  If it is intended as a normal question, it probably wouldn't be a good idea to create questions that are bad examples of what a question should be (especially where you might be in a position to close some other new question as overly broad).  A question should be judged on its own merits, not on the answers it receives.

That said, there's nothing that precludes answers from being comprehensive or tutorials.  The trick is to write the question as something focused, that could potentially be well-answered within the site's intended scope.

It doesn't even hurt for the question to suggest in closing, words to the effect that any other relevant information or suggestions would be appreciated.  That can serve to keep an "overly broad" answer as appearing all responsive.  But the statement should clearly not imply that it's extending the scope of the question, or that for an answer to be judged responsive and good, the other stuff must be included.

Then post an answer that goes beyond the minimum of addressing what was asked.  And if parts of the answer get too far removed from the specifics of what the question asked, include some connective wording to tie it in.  The answer should look like it's all responsive to the question, and not throwing in everything but the kitchen sink to unnecessarily make it long and "comprehensive".

There are a few ways to do that, depending on the nature of the question.  For example:

- Organize the answer so it directly answers the question in the first part, then add a section like "Other Considerations".
- For something like a tutorial, explain at the beginning that there are variations on the steps, so the answer will cover the whole process to provide a complete solution that works for you.

Comment: A very sensible approach :) Thank you!